# Benefits of Moving Bower Components before using?

Tags: gruntjs, zurb-foundation, gulp, bower

When using Bower Components, I tend to link directly to the files located in the `bower_components` directory. For example when I work with Foundation, here is how I link my JavaScript file:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js'></script>
```

However, I've noticed a lot of people copy the Bower components to a `library` directory (using Gulp or Grunt) and then use the components from there. Is there a benefit to doing things that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe developers choose to pipe their components through gulp or grunt to control the dependencies through source control and to have a safer way of using their dependencies in case one just stops working. [This article](http://addyosmani.com/blog/checking-in-front-end-dependencies/) might be able to help you understand.